# scanf two dimensional char array from [1][1]

Tags: c

I'm trying to 'scanf' two dimensional array from arr[1][1]

first,

```
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
    scanf("%s",arr[i]);
}
```

If I write a code like above,
contents start from `[1][0]~[n][0]`.

But I want to start from `[1][1]`.

I think

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++) for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
    scanf(" %c", &arr[i][j]);
```

is possible, but, is there any efficient way?

I tried...

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    scanf("%s",(&arr[i][0]+1)) 
    // or scanf("%s",&(*arr[i]+1)) //compile error..
```

but it failed.

Comment: This is C; stop fighting zero-based indexing and embrace it. And post a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits your problem.

Comment: What would be the expected behavioural change by starting from `[1][1]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly @WhozCraig comment is correct, you should try to use zero base indices because otherwise you're wasting memory and making it harder to code in general.
Other than that your example with the two loops is the only way to do it and there is no more efficient way, if you want to read into the whole array you'll need to traverse it all.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Actually i'm studying problem solving(algorithm), so i needed to start from [1][1]. Thank you.

Comment: @SEONGWOOCHAE: If you need to start from `[1][1]`, you have to make sure your arrays are big enough that you have enough space — by adding one to the dimensions, usually.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yeah, In problem solving(PS), i can have a enough space. when i handle data in PS, array starting from [1][1] is very convenient for me. and, i wanted to know about syntax, why &arr[0][1]+1 is invalid... anyway, these are reasons why i questioned.